# How to use symbols in SQL column names?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle8i

I tried to use column names with symbols like minus, dot and a few others. Oracle SQL parser doesn't except them. Like this:

```
select
    a.ID as Article-Number, a.Name as Name
from
    Articles a
where
    (a.ID = '3264')
```

And it doesn't except `a.ID as 'Article-Number'` (says `"FROM keyword not found where expected"`). Can I have symbols in column names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use double quotes (`"`) to escape aliases and column names:

```
select
    a.ID as "Article-Number", a.Name as "Name"
from
    Articles a
where
    (a.ID = '3264')
```

Comment: Hmpf, my bad. I didn't try double quotes. I thought `"` and `'` were just the same in Oracle and I just prefer `'` because I don't have to escape them in C#.

Comment: `name` alias is fine, it doesn't need `double-quotation` marks.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I went for consistency (although you're correct, of course).

Comment: @LalitKumarB I'm automating stuff here so all my aliases will get double quotes. Important is that I know how to use any strings in my aliases.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is only with `Article-Number` as an alias. The alias `name` is perfectly fine.

```
SQL> select e.ename as name from emp e where rownum = 1;

NAME
----------
SMITH

SQL> select e.ename as Article-Number from emp e where rownum = 1;
select e.ename as Article-Number from emp e where rownum = 1
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected


SQL> select e.ename as "Article-Number" from emp e where rownum = 1;

Article-Nu
----------
SMITH

SQL>
```

So, `double-quotation` marks are required only for `Article-Number` as alias to escape `-`.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I have symbols in column names?
>
> I'm automating stuff here so all my aliases will get double quotes. Important is that I know how to use any strings in my aliases.

In Oracle you use double quotes (`"`) to escape schema's name (incl. column names).

However, if you're trying to automatize things, there are several rules you should be aware of:

- names must be from 1 to 30 characters. Identifier exceeding this limit will raise 
  `ORA-00972: identifier is too long`
- names cannot contain quotes (`"`) nor the `\0` (aka nul) character

See [*Oracle's Schema Object Naming Rules*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

1.
I guess use bracket []

```
Select [Name@Symbol], [#Sharp!#Column] from Your table
```

before this you need create by this names

2.
you can use synonym for use 2 names or more than...

if you need this way in comment say.

TKU